# Zalenium, cannot use more than 3 containers

Tags: c#, selenium, docker, zalenium

I am using zalenium/docker to create a dockerized solution for selenium grid. On first launch time the tests run normally on all created containers(containers are created before test run).However, I am failing to get more than 3 containers to run my tests when I run the tests for the second time. I am quite new to this topic, maybe I am doing something wrong with the tests themselves. I run them in parallel (C#). The tests themselves do complete all the time, but the amount of time it takes to complete them could be improved with more containers. Here is my command and params:

> docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -v
>   /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v
>   /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start
>   --desiredContainers 8 --maxDockerSeleniumContainers 8 --maxTestSessions 4

I have docker installed on windows 10 machine for now.

UPDATE:
In the /grid/console view there is this line:

> 1 requests waiting for a slot to be free. Capabilities {browserName:
>   firefox, platform: LINUX, zal:name: myTestName2}

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Zalenium are you running?
I believe the fixed the issue with this: https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/322

Comment: I am not sure how to check the version. I pulled the dosel/zalenium image and ran it. How can I specify the version? Maybe there is a better way to run it than what is in the documentation?

Comment: I believe you are just experiencing the default behavior of Zalenium.

Whenever there is a test request, Zalenium first checks for available nodes with remaining test sessions, if it doesn't find any it creates a new node.

That means if your tests are fast and Zalenium is cleaning up the node after the test run, the request will wait in the queue until that is done.